# get only row value as integer in cassandra get query?

Tags: cassandra

I am very new to the cassandra, Is there any command to get only the value from column family in cassandra?

if I use the below command:

```
[default@CustomKeySpace] get user['peter'];
=> (column=friday, value=10, timestamp=1362290522592000)
```

I get:

```
Returned 1 results.
Elapsed time: 8.4 msec(s).
```

In the above result can I grab only the value section?
If I give a command something like `get user['peter'][xxx]`, I should get output value 10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in Cassandra (be it cli or cqlsh), as the unit of storage returned by thrift is always column, value, timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Your command

```
get user['peter'];
```

is reading in the whole row peter, which could contain many columns.  In your case it just has one, friday.  To retrieve that you can use

```
get user['peter']['friday'];
```

assuming your column comparator is a string type, otherwise you can use

```
get user['peter'][ascii('friday')];
```

However, this will still print the timestamp because there is a timestamp associated with each column.  When you write code you will get back a column object from which you can extract just the value.